# Check pixels are Gaussian distribution or not with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I need the check all bright spots in a image have Gaussian distribution or not. How to do that with python and opencv?
Is there any easy way?

I tried with Histogram . But it is just shows the result, not it is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I got your question right but to test if something has a normal distribution I would recommend to run a normal-test using sklearn: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html

A more general approach would be to use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test which compares two given distributions. In your case it would be the given pixels of an image and a generated normaldistribution. I would guess this documentation should give you some more details:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html